# React - Setting a variable to a function return not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set a variable to a function's return but it's not setting for some reason. Here's my code...

```
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

const cookies = new Cookies();

export default function Basic(props) {
  function getEmail(SubscriberToken) {
    let body = {
      AccessToken: cookies.get("AccessToken"),
      SubscriberToken: SubscriberToken,
    };
    let email;
    axios
      .post("/networkoperatorconsole/subscribers/getSubscriberEmail", body, {
        headers: {},
      })
      .then((response) => {
        email = response.data.email;
        console.log(email);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        //this.setState({error: true});
      });
    return email;
  }

  const userAttributes = [];
  let i = 0;
  console.log(props.subscriberName);

  props.subscriberName.forEach((el) => {
    let subscriberName = getEmail(el);
    console.log(subscriberName);
    userAttributes.push({
      number: i + 1,
      subscriberName: getEmail(el),
    });
    i = i + 1;
  });
}
```

I'm trying to set subscriberName to the function getEmail which should return an email address based off a user name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `axios.post` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so your code in `then` and `catch` blocks is out from flow and your `return email` is calls immediately.

That's why it doesn't return anything.

To fix this you should use for example [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Your code will be look like this:

```
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

const cookies = new Cookies();

export default function Basic(props) {
  async function getEmail(SubscriberToken) {
    let body = {
      AccessToken: cookies.get("AccessToken"),
      SubscriberToken: SubscriberToken,
    };
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/networkoperatorconsole/subscribers/getSubscriberEmail",
        body,
        {
          headers: {},
        }
      );

      return response.data.email;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const userAttributes = [];
  let i = 0;
  console.log(props.subscriberName);

  props.subscriberName.forEach(async (el) => {
    let subscriberName = await getEmail(el);
    console.log(subscriberName);
    userAttributes.push({
      number: i + 1,
      subscriberName: getEmail(el),
    });
    i = i + 1;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I have one more question. When I do a console.log of userAttributes after I push the data into the array it comes out empty.

Comment: Show how you do that please. You show your code using pastebin.com

Comment: I appreciate the help! Here's the pastebin...https://pastebin.com/RY79ym15

Comment: that's not working but like I said I appreciate the help!